# Redcarpet markdown removes my own CSS in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, markdown, redcarpet

I'm trying to implement Redcarpet Markdown in my Rails project.

I have a class 'camp-description' which styles the paragraph. My problem is that when I add the markdown() inside my ERB tag then the styles of camp-description is not applied anymore.

This is my code:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h5>TRAINING CAMP PROGRAM</h5>
    <p class="camp-description"><%= markdown(@camp.agenda) %></p>
</div>
```

The output html looks like this:

[image]

How do I make sure that the markdown stays inside the 'camp-description' class and hence keep applying its styles?

Comment: You can assign `camp-description` to `div` instead of `p` tag.

Comment: So simple. That solved the problem. Thx